# Quantum computing Justin Trudeaus explanation how much valid?

Tags: quantum-computing

What is the difference between normal computer and a quantum computer ? Was Justin Trudeau's explanation about quantum computing correct ?

Comment: Here's a video I found helpful (and accessible for most) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhHMJCUmq28

Comment: That was a very nice video thanks

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, yes he is correct!

The basic idea for quantum computing is to encode information in quantum systems.  The encoding is still binary (0 or 1), except for the fact that you can now be in a superposition of both 0 and 1.  The binary-bit of information encoded as such is called a quantum bit (Qubit).  This will allow the user to simulate efficiently quantum systems, since the encoding is, itself, quantum!

A somewhat naive way to think about quantum calculus is that you build entanglement between your different Qubits and then consume it to perform your computation.  You could say you use entanglement as a resource!

If you know a bit about physics, you could make a comparison with Young's experiment of interference fringes too.  In Young's experiment, a photon goes through both holes and interferes with itself constructively or destructively depending on both path lengths;
In a quantum computation, you would create a superposition of all possible answers, both good and wrong answers.  The computation consists of getting the wrong answers to interfere destructively with themselves and getting the good answer to interfere constructively..

Comment: And btw, this is a somewhat naive view of quantum computing, though not completely wrong.  It is hard to explain simply what really happens during a quantum computation since there are no classical equivalent to some of the quantum phenomenons that are being exploited!